# DB:SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `call-request`(`mob`, `dat`, `nam`) VAULES( `hello`, `hi`, `he`)";

    $result = $db->exec($sql);
    $insertId = $db->lastInsertId();
```

is getting this error

```
 DB:SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VAULES( 'hello', 'hi', 'he')' at line 1
```

I have not using any keywords please help

Comment: It's spelled `VALUES `not `VAULES`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- can we close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `call-request`(`mob`, `dat`, `nam`) VAULES( `hello`, `hi`, `he`)";
```

> VAULES

It should be VALUES

and the query should be look like below -

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `call-request`(`mob`, `dat`, `nam`) VALUES( 'hello', 'hi', 'he')";
$result = $db->query($sql);
```

for value you have to use single quote or double quote not `

Answer (score 0):

Use `'` to quote string literals and typo in `VALUES`:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `call-request`(`mob`, `dat`, `nam`) VALUES( 'hello', 'hi', 'h')";
```

Comment: @AmalPrasad `VALUES`